# Get total of a key after aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs

So basically there are a lot of key just like appointment_summary which have sub keys, I want a separate key called totals which will have the same structure but no grouping by date, rather total of all the sub-keys which fall between the given start and end dates.

```
 {
      "franchise_id": 3,
      "start_date": "2017-07-01",
      "end_date": "2017-07-07",
      "appointment_summary": {
        "2017-07-01": {
          "no_of_appointments": 2,
          "no_of_services": 2,
          "revenue_before_discount": "2250.00",
          "revenue_after_discount": "2250.00",
          "discount_percentage": "0.00",
          "revenue_per_service": "1125.00",
          "revenue_per_appointment": "1125.00"
        },
        "2017-07-02": {
          "no_of_appointments": 1,
          "no_of_services": 1,
          "revenue_before_discount": "250.00",
          "revenue_after_discount": "250.00",
          "discount_percentage": "0.00",
          "revenue_per_service": "250.00",
          "revenue_per_appointment": "250.00"
        },
        "2017-07-03": {
          "no_of_appointments": 1,
          "no_of_services": 2,
          "revenue_before_discount": "1150.00",
          "revenue_after_discount": "977.50",
          "discount_percentage": "15.00",
          "revenue_per_service": "488.75",
          "revenue_per_appointment": "977.50"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to get a total key which will have the total of appointment summary sub sections, like:

```
{
  "franchise_id": 3,
  "start_date": "2017-07-01",
  "end_date": "2017-07-07",
  "appointment_summary": {
    "2017-07-01": {
      "no_of_appointments": 2,
      "no_of_services": 2,
      "revenue_before_discount": "2250.00",
      "revenue_after_discount": "2250.00",
      "discount_percentage": "0.00",
      "revenue_per_service": "1125.00",
      "revenue_per_appointment": "1125.00"
    },
    "2017-07-02": {
      "no_of_appointments": 1,
      "no_of_services": 1,
      "revenue_before_discount": "250.00",
      "revenue_after_discount": "250.00",
      "discount_percentage": "0.00",
      "revenue_per_service": "250.00",
      "revenue_per_appointment": "250.00"
    },
    "2017-07-03": {
      "no_of_appointments": 1,
      "no_of_services": 2,
      "revenue_before_discount": "1150.00",
      "revenue_after_discount": "977.50",
      "discount_percentage": "15.00",
      "revenue_per_service": "488.75",
      "revenue_per_appointment": "977.50"
    }
  },
  {
    "total": {
      "appointment_summary": {
        "no_of_appointments": 4,
        "no_of_services": 5,
        "revenue_before_discount": "3650.00",
        "revenue_after_discount": "3477.50",
        "discount_percentage": "15.00",
        "revenue_per_service": "1863.75",
        "revenue_per_appointment": "2352.50.00"
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this all in the same document? If so then it's kind of pointless to ask the server to "aggregate" information in the same document since you can just do that as you read it, and in "a lot less code". You really only should be asking the server to do things when you 1. Are "aggregating across documents". 2 It actually "significantly" reduces the size of the results returned. This does neither and in fact "increases" the size of returned results. So it would be counter productive to ask the server to do this.

Comment: Yes it is all in the same document, do you mean to get the totals section I should do post processing after getting the result data segregated by dates (as shown first)?

Comment: Yes you should just do post processing. You are "increasing" the size of results. You do not want to ask the database client to send "more" data to your API. Unless you want really large data transfer bills from your provider. So "ideally" the "smallest possible" data should go direct to the end point. Then you can code to "expand". Pretty basic calculations to iterate through the object keys. Re-tagging to JavaScript, because that's what you really want here.